# Does Ubuntu 19.04 has an installation bug?

Tags: boot, 19.04

My Ubuntu 19.04 is a torrent download from April 18. It does not start after installation.

On my 128GB SSD I have a 60GB partition for Windows and two 30GB partitions for Ubuntu and of course another 4GB for SWAP. One Ubuntu partition holds Ubuntu 18.10. That version of Ubuntu works. Into the other Ubuntu partition I tried to install Ubuntu 19.04. I tried that three times. It came up with different problems. Once I was able to key in my password, but it stayed in a loop, asking me again and again to key in my password. In other cases the screen was scrambled. So I thought, it might be a defect of my SSD.

So instead of 19.04 I installed into that partition a second version of Ubuntu 18.10. That installed flawlessly.

I then installed Ubuntu 19.04 into the partition which was holding the original version of Ubuntu 18.10. Again Ubuntu 19.04 did not start. It kept asking me for my password in a never ending loop.

What can I do to make Ubuntu 19.04 run on my ASRock PC?

Comment: I have that prblem sometimes with Ubuntu 18.10
I try to lock __Super (Windows)+L__ or change the __change foreground virtual terminal__ with pressing __Ctrl+Alt+Fn__ where n is 1,2,..., or 7.
What results do you get then?

Comment: The result of your proposal was, that it made things worse. Now also the formerly working version of Ubuntu 18.10 crashed. So I had to install 18.10 from scratch. At the end of installing 18.10 I was aked to upgrade to 19.04. I followed that proposal and ended up with another not working installation. Now I have installed 18.10 another time without upgrading to 19.04 and everything is fine now. 19.04 seems to be still unstable.

Comment: Look up Ubuntu bugs at launchpad.net. If not already reported, please report it with sufficient detail for a Bug Triager to duplicate the problem on their test machine.

Comment: What is a Bug Triager?